# Android JobScheduler: using setMinimumLatency with setPeriodic

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm just playing around with `JobScheduler`, and have a couple of niggles.

One of them is that, although you can delay a job by using `setMinimumLatency()`, you cannot use that in combination with `setPeriodic()`, since an Exception is raised.

I cannot really understand why this is the case... it seems to be reasonable to delay the start of a periodic job, just as it is reasonable to delay the start of a one-off job.

Given that you cannot, what is the best way of scheduling a periodic job that starts in the future (even after a reboot), using `JobScheduler`?

Comment: "why isn't it reasonable..." -- "why did Developer X do Thing Y" questions aren't great for Stack Overflow, as only Developer X can authoritatively answer the question. "what is the best way..." -- off the cuff, either schedule the job now and have your job service skip over jobs for which it is not yet time, or use `AlarmManager` to get control at the time you want the jobs to start.

Comment: Well I have everything working just fine with `AlarmManager` already, but I thought that `JobScheduler` was the recommended way forward.  The main reason I'm looking at moving to using `JobScheduler` is because listening for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` in my `AppWidgetProvider` is no longer possible in Android N.  So I'm going from an `AlarmManager` solution with a connectivity-listening bolt-on to a `JobScheduler` (connectivity-listening) solution with... an `AlarmManager` bolt-on.  Hey ho.

Comment: P.S. the "why isn't it reasonable" question was rhetorical... I've rephrased it as a statement.

Comment: "I thought that JobScheduler was the recommended way forward" -- well, it is, for a certain class of work. It's not going to solve all possible classes of work. You wouldn't use it for an alarm clock, or for calendar reminders, for example. Your planned use case happens to not neatly align with any single API.

Comment: Yep I'm using the `AlarmManager` for scheduling periodic widget refreshes (with more flexibility than allowed by the stock `AppWidgetProvider` methods, including refreshing after restoring connectivity when a refresh was missed).  It's all working beautifully... but now they've taken away `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` :-(  Maybe I need to keep my `AlarmManager` framework intact and just schedule a `JobService` (to get the connectivity listening) on each refresh Alarm rather than start a `Service` straight off, as at present.

Comment: FirebaseDispatcher does the perfect job, you don't need to handle differently for all the APIs , it does the job using JobService, Alarm Manager and GCM Service accordingly. You can also try Worker Manager , it just got released though. But with Firebase , you will have to handle jobs after rebooting but I thing Worker Manager handles that part as well (Haven't tried it yet)

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation of `JobService` class, call `jobFinished(params, reschedule);` to reschedule before leaving `onStartJob` method.

Also don't forget to `return true` in `onStopJob` method to reschedule as well.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html#jobFinished(android.app.job.JobParameters, boolean)