# Android JobScheduler: job with time constraints

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

With `JobScheduler` it is possible to build a `JobInfo` with certain constraints, like "only when charging" and/or "only when idle" and/or "only when connected to unmetered (e.g. WiFi) network".

Is it possible to specify constraints on *when* the job is run, like "not between 9.15am and 10.15am"?  So you may have this in combination with "only with WiFi", so that if WiFi comes on at 9.30am then all constraints are not yet satisfied and it waits until 10.15am to run.

With a one-off job this seems possible to some extent with `builder.setMinimumLatency()` and `builder.setOverrideDeadline()`, but what about for a periodic job established with `builder.setPeriodic()` (it's not possible to use that in combination with the others)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to specify constraints on when the job is run, like "not between 9.15am and 10.15am"?

No, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for telling it like it is.  Shame.  Maybe in future.

Comment: Are you able to shed some light on a related issue?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310407/android-jobscheduler-using-setminimumlatency-with-setperiodic

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this don't know it follows good practices or not but your work will be done ;)

```
void timeCheck() {
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(date));
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(date));
    int remainingHours = 10 - hour;
    int remainingMinutes = 15 - minute;
    long timeRemainingInMinutes = remainingHours * 60 + remainingMinutes;
    if (timeRemainingInMinutes >= -60 && timeRemainingInMinutes < 0) {
         yourTask();
    } else {
         // startTimer and on remaining time complete do your task 
    }
}
```